# dropdownlist doesn't save when added js

Tags: javascript, php, yii

When I remove `name` the selected dropdown item does get save into the database. When I add in the `name` field it doesn't get saved. The `name` goes to js where an input field will show up, and the input field gets saved. Why is it not saving the selected dropdown item then?

```
<td><p><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'product_type', CHtml::listData(ProductType::model()->findAll(),'product_type','description'), 
        array(
        'class'=>'span12',
        'name'=>'prodType',
        'empty'=>"-- Select Type of Product --")); ?></td>                                  
<td><?php echo $form->error($model,'product_type'); ?></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('p select[name="prodType"]').change(function(e){
              if ($('p select[name="prodType"]').val() == "Pre"){
                $('#pre-input').show();
              }else{
                $('#pre-input').hide();
              }
            });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. The name is conflicting with something in a query, just print out the query that update the DB and you will see the problem

Comment: not sure what you mean? I also renamed the name, same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is probably something like this..

```
class MyController extends CController {
   .....
   public function actionSaveMyForm(){
        ....
        if(isset($_POST['MyModel']){
            $model->attributes = $_POST['MyModel'];
            $model->save();
        }
        .... 
   }
}
```

This is basically means if the array of `MyModel` is set in your `$_POST`, then assign all sub array elements to model attributes and then save them.

When you do not the set the name attribute in the `dropDownList` function call the auto-generated id attribute would be `MyModel_<<attribute>>` i.e. `MyModel_product_type` and the name attribute would be `MyModel[product_type]` Therefore when you send the form information, it will be available under `$_POST['MyModel']` array. i.e. product type can be retrieved from `$_POST['MyModel']['product_type']`
therefore

```
            if(isset($_POST['MyModel']){
                $model->attributes = $_POST['MyModel'];
                $model->save();
            }
```

would assign product_type value `$model->product_type` and save it.

However when you assign the name manually, the value is gettable only at `$_POST['myCustomName`]` so you will have to save it specifically like this

```
            if(isset($_POST['MyModel']) && isset($_POST['myCustomName')){
                $model->attributes = $_POST['MyModel'];
                $model->product_type = $_POST['myCustomName'];
                $model->save();
            }
```

then the model will get saved correctly.

**Note**: In addition to this you will have to change your JavaScript or form submit code to send the data correctly including your custom name field, along with the POST request